# Why do i get this error? discord.js dmall

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i'm trying to do a small command in discord.js

The problem is that when i do c/dmall i receive for 5 times the message.

```
        if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('c/dmall')) {
            let guild = message.guild
          let text = msg.content.slice('c/dmall'.length);
          guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
            if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(text);
          });
        }
      });
```

This is my code, can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You most likely be running 5 instances of the bot running. Check either commend line or terminal whether you the bot running multiple times in difference commend line or terminal

Comment: I will try that! thank you